# How to load same page again in laravel using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

my function for removing the cart from a panel:

```
function removeFromCart(key) {
    $.post('{{ route('cart.remove') }}', {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', key: key}, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        updateNavCart();
        $('#cart-summary').empty().html(response.data);
        toastr.warning('{{\App\CPU\translate('Item has been removed from cart')}}', {
            CloseButton: true,
            ProgressBar: true
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use This To Reload Your Page From Ajax.

```
location.reload();
```